# CDIST is choosing wrong value sometimes

Tags: python, spatial

I need to get the closest point from a given point in a screen ( X,Y ), from a list.
My code is almost right:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def closest_detection(centroid,objects):
    lista = []
    for item in objects:
        lista.append([item[5],item[6]])        
    if len(objects)>0:        
        return objects[cdist([centroid], lista)[0].argmin()]
    else:
        return [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

centroid = (195,139)

list=[
  [0,0,0,0,0,190,143,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,293,66,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,305,55,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,246,87,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,264,47,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,318,82,0,0]
  ]


print(closest_detection(centroid,list))
```

In this example in a raspberry it returned to me the `list[1]` but when I try to run it in my computer alone it returned me `list[0]`

Is there a good way (and safer) to return the list item that is closest to my given X,Y point?

Comment: Does this version of your approach always get a correct result on both machines? `points = np.array([[190, 143], [293, 66], [305, 55], [246, 87], [264, 47], [318, 82]]); print(points[np.argmin(cdist(np.array([[195, 139]]), points))])`

Comment: no. some times return to me a wrong value. ( second closer ). But its randon

Comment: You could do without `scipy`: `points[np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(points - np.array([195, 139]), axis=1))]`

Comment: nice i will try it